# Read txt files sequentially using Python

Tags: python

I have a problem reading txt files in order. I would like to read the files in the following order:

```
0.txt
1.txt
2.txt
...
10.txt
11.txt
...
19.txt
20.txt
21.txt
...
```

However, the following codes

```
import os

path = "temp/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

for filename in sorted(dirs):
    print filename
```

returns

```
0.txt
1.txt
2.txt
10.txt
11.txt
...
19.txt
2.txt
20.txt  
...
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sorting the names literally, instead you can use a key function in order to sort the names based on the integer value of the names:

```
for filename in sorted(dirs, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0])):
    print filename
```

Note that if one of your file names doesn't follow the proper format the sorted might raise an exception.

Comment: Can I use glob.glob instead of os.listdir?                                                                                                                                                                                              dirs = glob.glob('temp/')

for filename in sorted(dirs, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0])):
    print filename

Comment: @kevin if you want all content of your path, this is the straightforward way, otherwise if you want to filter the names by their format or etc. you can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module.